# Find coordinate for the third point of a triangle on the unit sphere, given the coordinates of the two points and their angles

Tags: spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

Suppose the Cartesian coordinates of the three points are $A,B,C,\|A\|=\|B\|=\|C\|=1$.

Given $A$,$B$ and $b=dist(B,C)$, $c=dist(A,C)$, how to find $C$?

Here, $dist(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the distance on the sphere, which is $dist(A,B)=\cos^{-1}(A\cdot B)$.

[image]

Can we find an accurate analytical form, other than just projecting the points to the tangent plane as an approximation and then projecting the third point back to the sphere?

Comment: Did you check the wikipedia article on spherical trigonometry? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry There is a section on solving triangles that looks useful.

Comment: There are two solutions. $C$ can be reflected through the plane $OAB$, and the distances and $A$ and $B$ don't change.

Comment: @ Logan Shi: Use the Law of Sines and Cosines.

Comment: @Narasimham - That only determines the triangle's lengths and angles, not the coordinates of its vertices (at least not directly).

Comment: Lat,long of two given  points given also?

Comment: @Narasimham - I'm assuming Cartesian coordinates, not spherical coordinates, since dot products are being used. But the OP could clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V=A\times_3B$, so that $A,B,V$ form a basis for $\mathbb R^3$. That means you should be able to write

$$C=\alpha A+\beta B+\gamma V$$

for some scalar coefficients $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. Taking dot products, we get three scalar equations:

$$A\cdot C=\alpha+\beta A\cdot B+0$$
$$B\cdot C=\alpha A\cdot B+\beta+0$$
$$V\cdot C=\;0\;+\;0\;+\gamma\lVert V\rVert^2$$

which you can solve for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ (e.g. using Cramer's rule), provided that you know all the other terms. But what are these other terms?

You already know $A\cdot B,\,A\cdot C,\,B\cdot C$, and the last term $\lVert V\rVert^2$ can be gotten from the identity

$$(A\cdot B)^2+\lVert A\times_3B\rVert^2=\lVert A\rVert^2\lVert B\rVert^2$$
$$\lVert V\rVert^2=1-(A\cdot B)^2.$$

Finally, $V\cdot C$ can be gotten from that same identity (along with [bac-cab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product)):

$$(C\cdot V)^2+\lVert C\times_3V\rVert^2=\lVert C\rVert^2\lVert V\rVert^2$$
$$(C\cdot V)^2+\lVert A(C\cdot B)-B(C\cdot A)\rVert^2=1-(A\cdot B)^2$$
$$(C\cdot V)^2+(C\cdot A)^2+(C\cdot B)^2-2(C\cdot A)(C\cdot B)(A\cdot B)=1-(A\cdot B)^2$$
$$C\cdot V=\pm\sqrt{1+2(A\cdot B)(A\cdot C)(B\cdot C)-(A\cdot B)^2-(A\cdot C)^2-(B\cdot C)^2}.$$

Putting all these pieces together, we find

$$C=$$
$$\frac{(A\cdot C)-(A\cdot B)(B\cdot C)}{1-(A\cdot B)^2}A$$
$$+\frac{(B\cdot C)-(A\cdot B)(A\cdot C)}{1-(A\cdot B)^2}B$$
$$\pm\frac{\sqrt{1+2(A\cdot B)(A\cdot C)(B\cdot C)-(A\cdot B)^2-(A\cdot C)^2-(B\cdot C)^2}}{1-(A\cdot B)^2}(A\times_3B).$$